# How do I use the DirectShow filewriter to output multiple segments to the same file?

Tags: directshow

I have created a DirectShow graph that is essentially:

```
      Mp4 file->mp4 demux->mp4 mux->file writer
```

In graphedit my graph runs and copies the source to the destination file perfectly.

In my code, I use IMediaSeeking to move between the clips that I want to export. This all works fine as long as I change the file name after each seek operation completes. I get notified of this as an EC_COMPLETE message from the graph.

If I don't change the file name only the last clip appears in the file.

For any large input file I could be extracting up to 100 five second clips so I don't want to have 100 files in my folder if I can avoid it. It appears as though the filewriter resets its internal file pointer to the start position each time I use IMediaControl.stop.

I've tried using the EC_END_OF_SEGMENT and IMediaControl.Pause but when I do that I don't get the clips at all. I get the right sequence of EC_COMPLETES or EC_END_OF_SEGMENT notifications but it's as if the filter has just stopped working.

Any ideas on how to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

The mux will write out the index and metadata to the file when you stop the graph. The best way is to separate the source graph from the mux/writer graph, using something like [GMFBridge](http://gdcl.co.uk/gmfbridge) to link the two graphs. Then you can change, seek or stop the source without stopping the mux.

Comment: Hi Geraint,  Thank you for answering. I was actually experimenting with your mp4 mux/demux in graphedit and VB.NET to achieve what I wanted. It's a small world! What you have suggested is a very elegant solution although it is a lot more work than I had in mind to accomplish something that I had hoped would be very straightforward. DirectShow in VB.NET has been a steep hill to say the least.

Comment: I have translated the VBPlay example from VB6 to VB.Net and it starts the first clip (and all the other clips are there too) but the End of Segment event never fires. I tried manually calling the "SetNotify" but that didn't seem to make any difference. Am I missing something?